# Notion and GitLab integration: how to do it?

Tags: gitlab, notion

I'm quite a newbie in Notion: I'd like to try the integration with GitLab using my GitLab account on gitlab.com. I've tried in a different way but I don't have any results in my Notion when trying the integration.

Is there documentation that shows step-by-step what I've to do? Do I need some third part tool (zapier or others)?

Are they strictly necessary?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a third party tool to integrate GitLab and Notion, they work natively together.
To integrate your GitLab account into your Notion account, you have to visit your settings (accessible in the side menu), click `my connections`, find GitLab at the bottom, and if not found - click `Show all` and find GitLab there. Choose `connect` - which will open a new browser tab, in which you sign in to your GitLab account and confirm the integration.
Additionally, if you are simply looking to embed GitLab into Notion, you can type `/GitLab` and enter the link there.
You can read more on the GitLab-Notion integration [in Notion's website](https://www.notion.so/integrations/gitlab-e719abb7-effd-42f1-aa3f-0f449710fdc0).

Comment: Ok it works, but I don't know how to show, for example in a table, the projects in my GitLab account, or the issues open in one of the my GitLab project, the board, and so on. Thank you in advance if you can tell me how in details as you've done before

Comment: I've found a way to insert a 'synced' database using a project from my public GitLab account as the source and now I can see my project issues. I'm still not sure how to insert a GitLab project in the 'embedded' mode within Notion. Any example / suggestion? Thanks

Comment: What if i have on premises Gitlab installation? Only works for the cloud version?

Comment: @JesúsCota Seems so. I'd also love to integrate our GitLab.